# Getting NoSuchMethoError While uploading file on Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I was trying upload the file in Amazon s3 bucket using the server-less architecture below is the described flow

ApiGateway->lambda->s3bucket

I am sending Request using postman, image is encoded into the base64 format and passed in key"base64" then convert it into inputstream and passing in `putObject` method but this where error is occurring it says
`NoSuchMethodError` for `puObject` method
but getting the below error

error stack trace:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception.setProxyHost(Ljava/lang/String;)V: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception.setProxyHost(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.AmazonS3ExceptionBuilder.build(AmazonS3ExceptionBuilder.java:266)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler.createException(S3ErrorResponseHandler.java:164)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler.handle(S3ErrorResponseHandler.java:71)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler.handle(S3ErrorResponseHandler.java:52)
at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handleAse(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:53)
at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:41)
at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:26)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1781)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1359)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5219)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5165)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:405)
at 
com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6180)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1824)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1784)
at com.nownow.aws.handler.MerchantOperationHandler.OperationHandler(MerchantOperationHandler.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Used method:

```
public Object OperationHandler(MerchantSignUpRequest merchantSignUpRequest, Context context)
{   SignUpResponse signUpResponse=new SignUpResponse();
 LOG.info(new Gson().toJson(merchantSignUpRequest));

    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
            .build();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date());
    String bucketName="nownowhub";String name="12345678.jpg";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(merchantSignUpRequest.getBase64().getBytes());

        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,name,is,new ObjectMetadata()).withCannedAcl(
                CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
        S3Object s3Object=s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                bucketName,name));

        return (s3Object.getObjectContent().getHttpRequest().getURI().toString());
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please make sure you are using same version `aws-java-sdk-core` and `aws-java-sdk-s3` and are of newest versions
for example:-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.883</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.883</version>
    </dependency>
```